# how to trim white space in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains some words. I want to get all words as unique part. so when I come to a whitespace , it's broken to a new. I mean , finally I want something like this:

```
$output[0]='Aug',
$output[1]='20',
$output[2]='2016'
```

first I want to explode it , then trim  between words . this is my code but unfortunately doesn't work.`Aug 20` come together. I want them individually.

```
<?php
$firs_arr=new array();
$first_arr='Aug 20, 2016   ';
$second=explode(',',$first_arr);
$output=array_map('trim',$second);
```

Comment: explode on space char, not comma. Trim commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call your source `$source`, then `$result` below is the array you want:

```
//split into parts separated by all non-word characters
$result = preg_split('/\W+/',trim($source));
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Es1dm)

Comment: You could split by `\W+` ;o/

Answer (score 1):

John John:
You can have a complete array with all the information of a given date inside a string, with the function **date_parse**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

**Code:**

```
$first_arr='Aug 20, 2016   ';
print_r(date_parse($first_arr));
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [year] => 2016 [month] => 8 [day] => 20 [hour] => [minute] => [second] => [fraction] => [warning_count] => 0 [warnings] => Array ( ) [error_count] => 0 [errors] => Array ( ) [is_localtime] => )
```

Comment: Oo I like this one. Anything rather than loading the beast that is a regex engine when you dont need to

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it:

```
<?php

function replaceComma($var){
    return str_replace(',','',trim($var));
}

$first_arr='Aug 20, 2016   ';
$second=explode(' ',trim($first_arr));
$second=array_map('replaceComma',$second);
var_dump($second);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) can do the job

```
$trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$first_array);
print_r($trimmed_array);
```

Comment: since this is already in the question, I don't see what this answer contributes. ;o/

Comment: Actually if you look closely `$first_arr` is a string! Dumb naming of a variable I admit